# App only works with first input, crashes after if second input is inserted

Tags: java, android

The app works as intended. A stock symbol is entered, enter button is pressed, and the data is pulled from yahoo webservice and is displayed on screen. However, after the first stock symbol is displayed, if i enter a new stock symbol, the app crashes.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.quickstockinfo;


import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;



import android.app.Activity;  
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText stocksymbol;
String stocksymbolstring;

Button enterbutton;

TextView CompanyName;
TextView YearLow;
TextView YearHigh;
TextView DaysLow;
TextView DaysHigh;
TextView LastPrice;
TextView Change;
TextView DailyPriceRange;

// XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "quote"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
    static final String KEY_YEAR_LOW = "YearLow";
    static final String KEY_YEAR_HIGH = "YearHigh";
    static final String KEY_DAYS_LOW = "DaysLow";
    static final String KEY_DAYS_HIGH = "DaysHigh";
    static final String KEY_LAST_TRADE_PRICE = "LastTradePriceOnly";
    static final String KEY_CHANGE = "Change";
    static final String KEY_DAYS_RANGE = "DaysRange";

    // XML Data to Retrieve
    String name = "";
    String yearLow = "";
    String yearHigh = "";
    String daysLow = "";
    String daysHigh = "";
    String lastTradePriceOnly = "";
    String change = "";
    String daysRange = "";

    // Used to make the URL to call for XML data
    String yahooURLFirst = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22";
    String yahooURLSecond = "%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

    // NEW STUFF

    // Holds values pulled from the XML document using XmlPullParser
    String[][] xmlPullParserArray = {{"AverageDailyVolume", "0"}, {"Change", "0"}, {"DaysLow", "0"},
            {"DaysHigh", "0"}, {"YearLow", "0"}, {"YearHigh", "0"},
            {"MarketCapitalization", "0"}, {"LastTradePriceOnly", "0"}, {"DaysRange", "0"},
            {"Name", "0"}, {"Symbol", "0"}, {"Volume", "0"},
            {"StockExchange", "0"}};

    int parserArrayIncrement = 0;

    // END OF NEW STUFF

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    stocksymbol = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.stocksymbol);

    enterbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enterbutton);

    CompanyName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stockName);
    YearLow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.YearLow);
    YearHigh = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.YearHigh);
    DaysLow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DaysLow);
    DaysHigh = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DaysHigh);
    LastPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LastPrice);
    Change = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Change);
    DailyPriceRange = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DailyPriceRange);

    enterbutton.setOnClickListener(enterbuttonlistener);


}

public OnClickListener enterbuttonlistener = new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(stocksymbol.getText().length() > 0){


            stocksymbolstring = stocksymbol.getText().toString();

            stocksymbol.setText(""); // Clear EditText box

            // Force the keyboard to close
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(stocksymbol.getWindowToken(), 0);
        } else {

            // Create an alert dialog box
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            // Set alert title 
            builder.setTitle("invalid stock symbol");

            // Set the value for the positive reaction from the user
            // You can also set a listener to call when it is pressed
            builder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);

            // The message
            builder.setMessage("missing stock symbol");

            // Create the alert dialog and display it
            AlertDialog theAlertDialog = builder.create();
            theAlertDialog.show();



        }// end else


        // Create the YQL query
        final String yqlURL = yahooURLFirst + stocksymbolstring + yahooURLSecond;

        new MyAsyncTask().execute(yqlURL);

    } //end onClick view v


}; //end button click event



private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    // String... arg0 is the same as String[] args
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // NEW STUFF

        try{

            Log.d("test","In XmlPullParser");

            // It is recommended to use the XmlPullParser because
            // it is faster and requires less memory then the DOM API

            // XmlPullParserFactory provides you with the ability to 
            // create pull parsers that parse XML documents

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

            // Parser supports XML namespaces
              factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

              // Provides the methods needed to parse XML documents
              XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser(); 

              // InputStreamReader converts bytes of data into a stream
              // of characters

              parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(getUrlData(args[0])));  

              // Passes the parser and the first tag in the XML document
              // for processing

              beginDocument(parser,"query");

              // Get the currently targeted event type, which starts
              // as START_DOCUMENT

              int eventType = parser.getEventType();

              do{

                // Cycles through elements in the XML document while
                // neither a start or end tag are found

                  nextElement(parser);

                  // Switch to the next element

                  parser.next();

                  // Get the current event type

                  eventType = parser.getEventType();

                  // Check if a value was found between 2 tags

                  if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT){

                      // Get the text from between the tags

                      String valueFromXML = parser.getText();

                      // Store it in an array with the corresponding tag
                      // value

                      xmlPullParserArray[parserArrayIncrement++][1] = valueFromXML;

                  }

              } while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) ;  

        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        finally {
        }

        // END OF NEW STUFF

        return null;
    }

    // NEW STUFF

    public InputStream getUrlData(String url) throws URISyntaxException, 
    ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        // Used to get access to HTTP resources

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Retrieves information from the URL

        HttpGet method = new HttpGet(new URI(url));

        // Gets a response from the client on whether the 
        // connection is stable

        HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);

        // An HTTPEntity may be returned using getEntity() which tells 
        // the system where the content is coming from

        return res.getEntity().getContent();
    }

    public final void beginDocument(XmlPullParser parser, String firstElementName) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
    {
        int type;

        // next() advances to the next element in the XML
        // document being a starting or ending tag, or a value
        // or the END_DOCUMENT

        while ((type=parser.next()) != parser.START_TAG
                       && type != parser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                ;
        }

        // Throw an error if a start tag isn't found

        if (type != parser.START_TAG) {
            throw new XmlPullParserException("No start tag found");
        }

        // Verify that the tag passed in is the first tag in the XML
        // document

        if (!parser.getName().equals(firstElementName)) {
                throw new XmlPullParserException("Unexpected start tag: found " + parser.getName() +
                        ", expected " + firstElementName);
        }
    }

    public final void nextElement(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
    {
        int type;

        // Cycles through elements in the XML document while
        // neither a start or end tag are found

        while ((type=parser.next()) != parser.START_TAG
                       && type != parser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                ;
        }
    }

    // END OF NEW STUFF

    // Changes the values for a bunch of TextViews on the GUI
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        CompanyName.setText(xmlPullParserArray[9][1]);
        YearLow.setText("Year Low: " + xmlPullParserArray[4][1]);
        YearHigh.setText("Year High: " + xmlPullParserArray[5][1]);
        DaysLow.setText("Days Low: " + xmlPullParserArray[2][1]);
        DaysHigh.setText("Days High: " + xmlPullParserArray[3][1]);
        LastPrice.setText("Last Price: " + xmlPullParserArray[7][1]);
        Change.setText("Change: " + xmlPullParserArray[1][1]);
        DailyPriceRange.setText("Daily Price Range: " + xmlPullParserArray[8][1]);

    }

}

}
```

LogCat:

> 07-20 15:29:02.914: W/asset(26417): Copying FileAsset 0x727a6928
>   (zip:/data/app/com.example.quickstockinfo-2.apk:/resources.arsc) to
>   buffer size 103468 to make it aligned. 07-20 15:29:03.064:
>   I/Adreno-EGL(26417): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM
>   build:
>   AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066_msm8974_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066__release_AU
>   () 07-20 15:29:03.064: I/Adreno-EGL(26417): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler
>   Version: E031.24.00.06 07-20 15:29:03.064: I/Adreno-EGL(26417): Build
>   Date: 02/06/14 Thu 07-20 15:29:03.064: I/Adreno-EGL(26417): Local
>   Branch:  07-20 15:29:03.064: I/Adreno-EGL(26417): Remote Branch:
>   refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066 07-20
>   15:29:03.064: I/Adreno-EGL(26417): Local Patches: NONE 07-20
>   15:29:03.064: I/Adreno-EGL(26417): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING 07-20
>   15:29:04.734: I/InputMethodManager(26417): [startInputInner]
>   EditorInfo { packageName=com.example.quickstockinfo,
>   inputType=0x20001, imeOptions=0x40000006, privateImeOptions=null },
>   windowGainingFocus=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41b654b8,
>   mServedView=android.widget.EditText{41b47ae0 VFED..CL .F....ID
>   574,0-1080,118 #7f05003d app:id/stocksymbol} 07-20 15:29:07.674:
>   I/InputMethodManager(26417): [startInputInner] EditorInfo {
>   packageName=com.example.quickstockinfo, inputType=0x20001,
>   imeOptions=0x40000006, privateImeOptions=null },
>   windowGainingFocus=null, mServedView=android.widget.EditText{41b47ae0
>   VFED..CL .F...... 574,0-1080,118 #7f05003d app:id/stocksymbol} 07-20
>   15:29:07.704: D/test(26417): In XmlPullParser 07-20 15:29:07.914:
>   D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 19(0x71756572792e79),sn(),family
>   0,flags 4 07-20 15:29:07.914: D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
>   07-20 15:29:07.914: D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn
>   19(0x71756572792e79),sn(),family 0,flags 1024 07-20 15:29:07.914:
>   D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1 07-20 15:29:07.914:
>   D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+ 07-20 15:29:07.934:
>   D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy-, success 07-20 15:29:07.934:
>   I/global(26417): call createSocket() return a new socket. 07-20
>   15:29:07.934: D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn
>   14(0x39382e3133372e),sn(),family 0,flags 4 07-20 15:29:07.934:
>   D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo-, SUCCESS 07-20 15:29:20.114:
>   I/InputMethodManager(26417): [startInputInner] EditorInfo {
>   packageName=com.example.quickstockinfo, inputType=0x20001,
>   imeOptions=0x40000006, privateImeOptions=null },
>   windowGainingFocus=null, mServedView=android.widget.EditText{41b47ae0
>   VFED..CL .F...... 574,0-1080,118 #7f05003d app:id/stocksymbol} 07-20
>   15:29:20.174: D/test(26417): In XmlPullParser 07-20 15:29:20.204:
>   D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 19(0x71756572792e79),sn(),family
>   0,flags 4 07-20 15:29:20.204: D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
>   07-20 15:29:20.204: D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn
>   19(0x71756572792e79),sn(),family 0,flags 1024 07-20 15:29:20.204:
>   D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1 07-20 15:29:20.204:
>   D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+ 07-20 15:29:20.214:
>   D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy-, success 07-20 15:29:20.214:
>   I/global(26417): call createSocket() return a new socket. 07-20
>   15:29:20.214: D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn
>   14(0x39382e3133372e),sn(),family 0,flags 4 07-20 15:29:20.214:
>   D/libc(26417): [NET] getaddrinfo-, SUCCESS 07-20 15:29:20.374:
>   W/dalvikvm(26417): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x416ebe18) 07-20 15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 07-20 15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):
>   Process: com.example.quickstockinfo, PID: 26417 07-20 15:29:20.374:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26417): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured
>   while executing doInBackground() 07-20 15:29:20.374:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26417):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300) 07-20 15:29:20.374:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26417):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   07-20 15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   07-20 15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) 07-20
>   15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 07-20
>   15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   07-20 15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   07-20 15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864) 07-20 15:29:20.374:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26417): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=13; index=13 07-20
>   15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):    at
>   com.example.quickstockinfo.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:231)
>   07-20 15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):  at
>   com.example.quickstockinfo.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   07-20 15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 07-20 15:29:20.374:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26417):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 07-20
>   15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417):    ... 4 more

Comment: your logcat says "array index out of bounds 13 of 13" line 231... are you surprised? And it would help if you highlighted that section of your code...

Comment: can you please help me with that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This declaration

```
int parserArrayIncrement = 0;
```

should be moved from line 87 into method

```
protected String doInBackground(
    int parserArrayIncrement = 0;
```

Comment: thank you very much laune! that worked. thank you to everyone else too for responding as well

Comment: Don't bother to send thanks, just accept the answer, OK?

Comment: You can indicate that you have accepted an answer by clicking on the tick mark. - LAter on, you can also click on the black "up" arrow to indicate that an aswer is valuable (if not the "accepted" one).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are not resetting your `parserArrayIncrement` during your second pass through. But that's just a guess without having line numbers and only having the "Array index out of range" error you posted...

Answer (score 0):

This line `15:29:20.374: E/AndroidRuntime(26417): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=13; index=13 07-20 15:29:20.374: ...`
means, that you try to access an index as big as the number of strings inside the array. Both is 13, but for arrays start counting with 0, you get an exception. 
In a quick way I can't see, where exactly the position of the issue is